# Pandas bar chart with unequal groups

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data with a hierarchical structure and want to create a plot with groups of bars.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
 ['alpha', 'x', 1],
 ['alpha', 'y', 2],
 ['alpha', 'z', 2],
 ['beta', 'x', 3],
 ['beta', 'z', 4]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['P','Q','R'])
df.pivot('P','Q','R').plot.bar(rot=0)
```

This code produces:

[image: code output]

How could I:

1. Eliminate the space for the missing bar, i.e. accommodate groups with different numbers of bars?
2. Make all the alphas blue and the betas orange, i.e. cycle the colors by group rather than within groups?

Comment: are you open to external libraries like `seaborn`?

Comment: Seaborn will not help here. It would instead require to create the bars manually with matplotlib's `bar` and calculate the respective positions.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest as always, you're correct when it comes to visualization! I thought I could mess with the `hue` argument somehow under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inspired by @MattR's answer, which showed me that plotting bars from scratch is not rocket science.  Pandas `groupby()` seems to be a good tool for this.

In the end I prefer it without extra space between groups.

```
    labels = []
    for g, grp in df.groupby('P'):
        plt.bar(grp.index, grp.R, label=g)
        labels.extend(grp.Q)
    plt.xticks(df.index, labels)
    plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure to get rid of empty cells but you can use a **stacked** parameter to get the output and also yes **you can pass the color array to bar** method which will display color accordingly.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
 ['alpha', 'x', 1],
 ['alpha', 'y', 2],
 ['alpha', 'z', 2],
 ['beta', 'x', 3],
 ['beta', 'z', 4]]

df =  pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['P','Q','R'])
df.pivot(index='P',columns='Q',values='R').plot.bar(rot=0, stacked=True,color = ['blue', 'green', 'red'])
```

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much!! Personally I prefer this method as it generalizes well, I'll make a minor edit to further show the clarification of the arguments passed to pivot.

Answer (score 2):

What if you create the plot "manually"? You can use `loc` to filter. Then plot on the same figure.

the magic for the space happens by using the index values. notice in `beta` I add +1 to the index to create that extra space. I then combine both indexes in `xticks` and then simply use `df['Q']` as the labels.

```
plt.bar(data=df.loc[df['P']=='alpha'], x=df.loc[df['P']=='alpha'].index, height='R', label='alpha')
plt.bar(data=df.loc[df['P']=='beta'], x=df.loc[df['P']=='beta'].index+1, height='R', label='beta')
plt.xticks(df.loc[df['P']=='alpha'].index.tolist() + list(df.loc[df['P']=='beta'].index+1),df['Q'].tolist())

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: That looks about right; let's see if I can parse those rather long lines of code...

Comment: If you don't object, I think I will mark my own answer as the accepted answer, although your answer helped.